# jScrollPane ignore scrollable zWeatherFeed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

i use [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/index.html#) for scroll verticaly blocks
but when i include in block [zweatherfeed](http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zweatherfeed/) block not scroll
so i add some  after weather div scrolling work

```
<div style="padding: 0px; width: 300px; overflow: hidden;" class="scroll-pane jspScrollable" tabindex="0">
   <div class="jspContainer" style="width: 300px; height: 190px;">
      <div class="jspPane" style="padding: 10px; width: 266px; top: 0px;">
         <div id="test" class="weatherFeed"></div>
         <div>1</div>
         <div>3</div>
         <div>4</div>
         <div>5</div>
         <div>6</div>
         <div>7</div>
         <div>8</div>
         <div>1</div>
      </div>
<div class="jspVerticalBar">
```

i add 13 for active scroll

Comment: Which script executes first? jScrollPlane inherits the height of the selected div, so after you execute jsPane any dynamic element you add later to your div will be ignored.

Comment: how can i undestand which script sxcute first?
i include wearher script before jscrollpane in header

Comment: Can you post your head? But first in your jPane add autoReinitialise: true http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/image.html

Comment: The head seems ok, but jPane is loading first. Also the autoReinitialize is not working.
In your #sourcecode you are invoking scrollpane multiple times, try to make it smaller. Just this should be enough $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane(
{autoReinitialise: true} If that doesn't work, move away your jsPane init from the head, and don't use $(function...

Comment: You should use $('#test').weatherfeed ... and $('.scrollpane').jScrollPane inside the same $(document).ready, instead of having those in different parts.

Comment: can you write this code?
i cant understand what should i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here how with autoReinitialise true it works... But I'm not sure why jsPane is loading first.

http://jsfiddle.net/ggS8b/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').weatherfeed(['UKXX0085','EGXX0011','UKXX0061','CAXX0518','CHXX0049']);

    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane( {autoReinitialise: true} )
});
```